# Setting number of channels to 10 objects

Tags: javascript

I want to limit each page with 10 objects. I am able to limit it but after 10 objects, in the next page i expect it to count from 11..20, 21...30 and so on but it starts again from 1..10. Please help me with this as i am new to this. I have also attached my code here.

if(pageTotal > actPage)

{

rep=10;

}

else

{

rep = remain;

}

pageName= (actPage-1)*10+1 + " .. " +  ((actPage-1)*10+rep)  ;

...
  [[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9se7k.png][1]

Comment: Can you please add a more elaborate example of your code and what you actually want to achieve?

Comment: As shown in the image attached, I am working on a project that needs little bit of java script. I want to limit each page to say 1..10. and the next page from 11...20 and the third page from 21...30.

Comment: Can you please show more code? Like where are the variables `actPage` and `pageTotal` set?